# Percona tool pt-table-sync

Tags: mysql, percona

Continue to get Access Denied errors when running `pt-table-sync` on mysql databases holding tables that `pt-table-checksum` found differences in the replicated tables.

```
[mysql@node1:0 ~]$ pt-table-sync --execute --verbose master.com  slave.com -uroot -ppasswd
DBI connect(';host=master.com;mysql_read_default_group=client','root',...) 
failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'master.com' (using password: YES) at /usr/bin/pt-table-sync line 2163
```

Running it from master server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It must be the way the tool is connecting to the server. Make sure any symbols or other characters in your password are escaped. Also, if you are connecting from a remote server, check to see if root access is enabled. Check out [this blog article](http://ptankov.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/howto-grant-and-revoke-remote-root-access-to-mysql/) for how to deal with the latter.

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html):

> If you get the following error, it means that you are using an
>   incorrect root password:
>
> shell> mysqladmin -u root -pxxxx ver Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) If the preceding error occurs
>   even when you have not specified a password, it means that you have an
>   incorrect password listed in some option file. Try the --no-defaults
>   option as described in the previous item.
>
> For information on changing passwords, see Section 6.3.5, “Assigning
>   Account Passwords”.
>
> If you have lost or forgotten the root password, see Section C.5.4.1,
>   “How to Reset the Root Password”.

Also perhaps helpful:

> You can suppress the use of option files by a client program by
>   invoking it with the --no-defaults option. For example:
>
> shell> mysqladmin --no-defaults -u root version
>   The option files that
>   clients use are listed in Section 4.2.3.3, “Using Option Files”.
>   Environment variables are listed in Section 2.13, “Environment
>   Variables”.

Comment: I appreciate you responding udog, but I only wish it was that simple. I tried pwd several times although it works with mysql and other tools such as pt-table-checksum. It is another issue.